# Chrome Extension: reposition browser action popup.html page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

Is there a way to reposition a chrome extension's browser_action's popup.html page somewhere other than the chrome extensions icon area (top right)? I'd like to be able to use my chrome extension in any tab whether it be on regular webpages or `chrome://` pages like (settings, bookmarks, etc).

Using a content script I can achieve what I want (purple modal), which is to bring up a modal where the user can start typing. However, I can't bring my modal up in `chrome://` pages since content-scripts can't load in these pages. The white modal in the top right corner (implemented through a popup action) can be invoked from anywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

What you specifically ask about is not possible. The [browser action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction)/[page action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction) popup is intentionally very limited in what you can do with it. You can not reposition it. What you can do with it is completely limited by the documented APIs, linked above, and the HTML/CSS/JavaScript which you display within the popup.

One possible alternative is that you could open your HTML page in a completely separate window using something like:

```
chrome.windows.create({url:'/myWindow.html'});
```

Doing so would at least give you, and the user, the ability to move that window. Through JavaScript, you can move that window using [`windows.update`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-update) to which you pass [`top`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#property-updateInfo-top) and [`left`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#property-updateInfo-left) properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the extension surfingkeys. It is a vim emulation and has multiple pop up menus in different locations. I think it is open source.

Comment: Looks interesting, but I can't use the extension in `chrome://` tabs like downloads, settings since main functionality for that extension lives in it's content scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but just found Vimium, which looks simpler, smarter and better :)
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb/related